# flickr4java: can't retrieve list of people in photo

Tags: flickr

I have uploaded a test photoset in flicker ([photoset](https://www.flickr.com/photos/24055070@N04/sets/72157649768209904/)) and the tagged a couple of users in each pic of the set.

Now I want to be able to retrieve the list of people in a given photo of that set, but the list always comes empty. This is my flickr4java code:

```
Flickr flickr;
PeopleInterface people=flickr.getPeopleInterface();

PersonTagList<PersonTag> persons= people.getList("17224159072");
for(PersonTag person:persons){
    System.out.println("UsER:"+person.getUsername()) }
```

The debugger shows that the photo indeed contains people

```
hasPeople=True
```

and even the API explorer is able to retrieve the list but, as I said, persons is always empty. I have no trouble retrieving other information.

Any ideas?

Thanks